# How to display calculated value in Label without submission? Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, jdatechooser

The situation is:
I want to use two date values obtained from two jDateChoosers and calculate the number of days between two selected days.
The question is: what should I do that after choosing both dates a calculated value would appear in a label (or Text Field, which one is better?) without any additional submission (in other words, without clicking on any buttons ect.)?

Answer (score 1):

Have an actionListener checking for if both dates have been input when the jDateChoosers close and then have a function such as update() to perform the calculations and update your label

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!